# Jquery Horizontal MouseWheel Scroll - Stop page from Vertically Scrolling as well

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

Lots of examples of how to scroll a div's contents horizontally. Problem is that when the element you are horizontally scrolling is in the middle of a page that is itself vertically scrollable (due to its contents being longer than the window size), the page scrolls as vertically as well as the div's content scrolling horizontally.

An example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/ ... just resize the RESULT window so that its shorter than the image, then use your mousewheel and you will see whats going on.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strange to answer my own question, but with more digging I found that adding  event.preventDefault(); makes it work perfect.  http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/72/

Answer (score 0):

I added a scroll(0,0) and it somewhat helps. http://jsfiddle.net/Detect/MvRdD/67/ Maybe it can be perfected....